# RowTable to List of KeyValue for Json Serialization

Tags: c#, linq

I have some data returned from a Mysql query that I am using Linq to paginate and need to get back a key value pair so I can later nest it in another List / Dictionary and serialize it to JSON later. I realize this should be a duplicate question, but I can't find any solutions that work for me.

My initial data source code looks like this:

```
var pageData = rawData.AsEnumerable().Skip(currentIndex * Config.PageSize)
    .Take(Config.PageSize);
```

I need to iterate through and convert each to a key value. The trick is that it will have different structure each time, so I can't hard code the column names. As a for instance, after serialization it may look like this:

```
{
  "reference_id": 19,
  "category": 2,
  "title": "Unconfirmed",
  "code": "Unconfrm"
}
```

or like this:

```
{
  "reference_id": 11,
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "first_name": "John",
  "pref_name": "",
  "status": 4,
  "gender": 0
}
```

I have this that is creating the key value pair, but it also adds it as a dictionary reference of `Data` instead of just adding another item to the Array / List.

```
var rows = new List<RowDto>();
foreach (var row in pageData)
{



    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    for (int index = 0; index < row.ItemArray.Length; index++)
    {
        dictionary.Add(row.GetColumn(index), row.ItemArray[index].ToString());
    }

    rowDto.Data = dictionary;
    rows.Add(rowDto);
}
public class RowDto
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I realize that in the class `RowDto` I am defining it as a Dictionary, but I can't figure out how to switch it to a List. Every time I do VS2017 complains that it can't convert (string, string) to int / string[] or anything else I have tried.

Comment: Try following :             var dictionary = rawData.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>(2), y => y.ItemArray.Select(z => (string)z))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

Comment: If you want to declare the dictionary :             Dictionary<string,List<string>> dictionary = rawData.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>(2), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.ToString()).ToList());